# React in plugins: REST endpoints vs. regular functions

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api

I'm building a plugin that uses React for the front-end management.

Is it correct that I should use regular functions for that vs creating REST endpoints, since I can access them directly from my plugin and not remotely? Are there any benefits in using REST?

Comment: What do you mean ‘regular’ functions?

Comment: I mean using calls via `admin-ajax` and corresponding functions in plugin.